# How to find direct path between two nodes in a graph in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I am new to Prolog and I'm trying to write a predicate that takes two nodes and a graph as it's arguments and then checks whether there exists a direct path between these two nodes in the graph.

For example, there is a  direct path from `n(1)` to `n(4)` in the graph below, that goes from `n(1)`
to `n(3)` and from `n(3)` to `n(4)`:

```
g[n(1), n(4), g([n(1), n(2), n(3), n(4), n(5), n(6), n(7), n(8)],
[e(n(1), n(2)), e(n(1), n(3)), e(n(3), n(4)), e(n(4), n(5)), e(n(5), n(6)), e(n(5), n(7)), e(n(7), n(8))]))
```

In the end

```
?− dirPath(n(1), n(4), g[n(1), n(4), g([n(1), n(2), n(3), n(4), n(5), n(6), n(7), n(8)],
[e(n(1), n(2)), e(n(1), n(3)), e(n(3), n(4)), e(n(4), n(5)), e(n(5), n(6)), e(n(5), n(7)), e(n(7), n(8))]))
```

should return `true.`

My tentative code looks like this:

```
edge(n(1),n(2)).
edge(n(1),n(3)).
edge(n(3),n(4)).
edge(n(4),n(5)).
edge(n(5),n(6)).
edge(n(5),n(7)).
edge(n(7),n(8)).

dirPath(A,B, g) :-   % - graph argument still missing.
  move(A,B,[])       % - two nodes are connected,
  .                  % - if one can move from one to the other,

move(A,B,V) :-       % -  and one can move from A to B
  edge(A,X) ,        % - if A is connected to X, and
  not(member(X,V)) , % - one hasn't yet reached X, and
  (                  % - either
    B = X            % - X is the desired destination
  ;                  %   OR
    move(X,B,[A|V])  % - one can get to that destination from X
  )                  
  .
```

My main problem is that I can't figure out how make my `dirPath` predicate accepts a graph, as it's argument.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this:

```
g[n(1), n(4), g([n(1), n(2), n(3), n(4), n(5), n(6), n(7), n(8)],
[e(n(1), n(2)), e(n(1), n(3)), e(n(3), n(4)), e(n(4), n(5)), e(n(5), n(6)), e(n(5), n(7)), e(n(7), n(8))]))
```

is not valid syntax. A term cannot begin `g[...`. This should probably be `g([...` instead.

Second, the representation is not entirely intuitive. What are the special roles of `n(1)` and `n(4)`? Why is there an inner `g(...)` term?

Nevertheless, it's clear which part is supposed to be the edges. Let's define a predicate to access just the edges:

```
graph_edges(Graph, Edges) :-
    Graph = g(_Something, _SomethingElse, g(_Nodes, Edges)).
```

Selection of one edge from the graph is then:

```
graph_edge(Graph, Edge) :-
    graph_edges(Graph, Edges),
    member(Edge, Edges).
```

You can then incorporate this into your predicate like this:

```
dirPath(A, B, Graph) :-
    move(A, B, Graph, []).

move(A, B, Graph, Vs) :-
    graph_edge(Graph, e(A, X)),
    ...
```

Note that I changed your variable `V` to `Vs`. Single-letter variable names are often not great in general (`From` and `To` would in my opinion be clearer than `A` and `B`). Single-letter variable names for *lists* are especially unusual; the common convention is to add `s` (as in the English plural, visited node**s**) for lists. For graphs this is *especially* recommended, since a simple `V` could very well be interpreted as a single "vertex".

(Solution not tested.)